# How to use a particular syntax table with arbitrary functions?

Tags: syntax-table, capitalization

I have an Elisp function which takes a string and performs capitalization (`capitalize`) on it, and then inserts it into a file. Apparently `capitalize` doesn't consider the single quote as a "word constituent" and therefore I get results like "I'M A Cat".

I understand that this is because of the syntax table in place. The default returned by `(standard-syntax-table)` treats the quote as a "word constituent", so I'm assuming that code execution uses `emacs-lisp-mode-syntax-table` which has it otherwise.

I tried executing `capitalize` inside `with-temp-buffer` but that didn't work for some reason.

So my questions are:

- Does the functions I have in my config use`emacs-lisp-mode-syntax-table` when I call them?
- What's the standard way of dealing with this? What's a way to isolate my functions from inheriting all this context? I don't want to manually create a new table and use `with-syntax-table` for every function in my config or change the current table using `modify-syntax-entry`, and I want my strings to be treated like normal English sentences.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: What's the mode of the buffer you are inserting into? The syntax table of that mode is what matters, so if you are inserting into a text-mode buffer, you should see the capitalization you expect. If you insert into an emacs-lisp buffer, you'll get capitalization according to *its* syntax table.

Comment: @NickD I'm not inserting it anywhere. I'm using it as a filename. I tried using `with-temp-buffer` hoping that the default table the buffer inherits would have apostrophe as a word constituent, but apparently that wasn't the case.

Comment: Then fix the question: the first sentence says `... and then inserts it into a file`. How are you using it as a filename? Are you inserting it into the minibuffer in response to a prompt? The minibuffer has its own syntax tables: `minibuffer-local-filename-syntax` and `minibuffer-inactive-mode-syntax-table`. I presume the first one is then what matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say you don't want to have to "manually create a new table and use `with-syntax-table` for every function in my config or change the current table using `modify-syntax-entry`."

I think you have to do either that or give yourself a more general function that you can apply to accomplish the same thing.

Here's a particular command, just for capitalizing the region the way you want:

```lisp
(defun my-capitalize-region (begin end)
  "..."
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((s-table  (copy-syntax-table)))
    (modify-syntax-entry ?' "w" s-table)
    (with-syntax-table s-table (capitalize-region begin end))))
```

You could use essentially the same code as a helper, to apply to a command, such as `capitalize-region` passed as an arg.

```lisp
(defun with-word-apostrophe (command &rest args)
  "..."
  (let ((s-table  (copy-syntax-table)))
    (modify-syntax-entry ?' "w" s-table)
    (with-syntax-table s-table (apply command args))))

(defun my-capitalize-region (begin end)
  "..."
  (interactive "r")
  (with-word-apostrophe #'capitalize-region begin end))
```

You can't just use `standard-syntax-table`, e.g.:

```lisp
(defun with-word-apostrophe (command &rest args)
  "..."
  (with-syntax-table (standard-syntax-table) (apply command args)))
```

because apostrophe has syntax *punctuation* in the standard syntax table:

```lisp
(aref (standard-syntax-table) ?') ; ==> (1), which means punctuation
```

Comment: Thanks, got it. I ended up doing something like this. `text-mode-syntax-table` was right for me.